# prevent form from submitting if invalid on css class

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hi I am using jQuery validate however I am trying to validate on specific css classes because of restrictions in the code, I have tried this:

```
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert('submitted'); 
            form.submit();
        }
    });

    $('#shopLeft .cart').validate();


    $('.addon-wrap-7479-basics-0 .addon-custom').rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 20,
    });


    $('.addon-wrap-7479-description-2 .addon-custom-textarea').rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 20,
    });


    $('.addon-wrap-7479-upload-3 .addon-custom').rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 20,
    });


    $('.product-addon-nameproject .addon-custom').rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
```

Can anyone help.

Comment: What is the problem with what you tried?  Where is the relevant HTML markup of your form?  There is nothing wrong with the syntax of the code you're showing, so there is nothing we can do if you don't explain this better.

Comment: I'll bet your jQuery selectors are broken, but we can't know for sure if we can't see the HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that the methods of the jQuery Validate plugin only work on the *FIRST matched element* when the selector contains multiple elements.

I see a lot of `class` selectors in your code, so I'm wondering if you're trying to target more than one element per each instance of `.validate()` and `.rules()`.  If so, you also need a jQuery `.each()`.

```
// more than one form with class="cart"
$('#shopLeft .cart').each(function() { // more than one form with class="cart"
    $(this).validate();
});


// more than one field with class="addon-custom" within a class="addon-wrap-7479-basics-0"
$('.addon-wrap-7479-basics-0 .addon-custom').each() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 20,
    });
});
```